# Looking to identify where to disable backup on CoreData managed persistent store

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, appstore-approval

I have located the required code necessary to apply the extended attribute to the DB file, however I am having an issue identifying exactly when to apply the attribute. The information I have located indicates that attempting to set the attribute at a point before the file exists will ensure that the setting will not take effect until the app restarts (and hits the code again), however I am not sure whether marker can be set while the DB is open, nor where, specifically the file is guaranteed to be opened in the `persistentStoreCoordinator`. I'm using the standard method structure generated for a CoreData application (originally included in the `AppDelegate`, just moved to a separate class to make supporting multiple db's easier):

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator {
    if (_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
    NSError *error = nil;
    _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:_storeURL options:nil error:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }
    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
```

I know I'm going to have to call `addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL` (from Apple sample code) on `_storeURL`, but am I correct in thinking I will also have to identify the extra files created by default on an SQL db (or turn off WAL on the db). Furthermore, I'm not certain when I will need to call this to ensure that the file is correctly marked on the first run. Primarily, am I guaranteed that the store files will all exist just before the return in this method, or are any of them not created until they are used, or after the managed object context is created, etc?

Comment: You can put everything you don't want backed-up into one folder and just mark that folder with the `addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL` That way you don't have to do it for new files you create.

Comment: I did consider that, but it is only the one DB that needs skipping, and doing it that way will mean the two active databases will be in separate areas - which isn't such a concern, but this way I also only have to change the flag to the DB control object to make the change, rather than having to remember to rebase the DB into the other location when I go to reuse this system. Basically, I prefer solving the problem once, rather than remembering to manage and coordinate separate spaces every time. =)